# Creating title pages with many centered lines each with different font sizes?

Tags: memoir, titles, fontsize, front-matter, titling

I'm trying to imitate a title page exactly like the following image. It's got a long title spread out across multiple lines, each having a different font size.

I'm using the Memoir class. What's the best way to emulate this kind of title page using LaTeX?

Note: I'm okay with duplication of the title's content. Meaning, I'm okay with having the \title just say "Life and Miracles of St. Benedict" whereas I manually put "The Life and Miracles of the Holy Father Benedict" (etc.) in another spot in the same document. The words are a bit duplicated in two places, but that's okay with me. I consider one the "official" title and one the "fancy" title.

Here's the code I want to turn into a title page like the image below:

```
The

Life and Miracles

of the

Holy Father Benedict.



Translated from the

Second Book of the Dialogues of St. Gregory the Great,

by the

Rev. Henry Formby.

Followed by the

Spirit of the Rule of St. Benedict,

By the

Right Rev. Dr. Ullathorne,

Bishop of Birmingham.
```

[image: ideal]

Comment: I'll clarify in an edit.

Comment: Can you post a document containing the text so that people only have to help with the markup? It is no fun copying text from an image in another application on another desktop! But I would basically use a `titlepage` environment: this is a one-off customised title so it is a waste of time creating macros to do semantic markup.

Comment: Any of those helping? https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples Especially `fox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example adapted from `memoir`'s documentation just to give you some ideas. See `titlepages.sty` in the documentation directory for further examples. I used an example from there as the basis so I wouldn't have to type stuff from scratch since no text was provided in the question at the time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\begin{document}

% adapted from titlepages.sty in memoir's documentation

\newcommand*{\covertext}{%
{\LARGE THE NEW\medskip\par}
{\HUGE FAMILY RECEIPT BOOK\bigskip\par}
{\normalsize CONTAINING A LARGE COLLECTION OF\par}
{\large HIGHLY ESTIMATED RECEIPTS IN A VARIETY\par}
{\large OF BRANCHES, NAMELY:\medskip\par}
{\HUGE BREWING,\smallskip\par}
{\Huge MAKING AND PRESERVING BRITISH WINES,\smallskip\par}
{\HUGE DYING,\smallskip\par}
{\huge RURAL AND DOMESTIC ECONOMY,\bigskip\par}
{\large SELECTED FROM EXPERIENCED \& APPROVED RECEIPTS,\medskip\par}
{\LARGE\textsf{FOR THE USE OF PUBLICANS}\medskip\par}
{\large AND HOUSEKEEPERS IN GENERAL,\medskip\par}
{\normalsize A GREAT MANY OF WHICH WERE NEVER BEFORE PUBLISHED.\par}
{\Huge
  \rule{0.25\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  \par BY G.~MILLSWOOD.\par}
{\large
\rule{0.75\textwidth}{0.4pt}\smallskip\par
\textsf{PRICE ONE SHILLING}\par}
{\large
  \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}\smallskip\par
  DERBY: PRINTED AND SOLD BY G.~WILKINS AND SON,\smallskip\par}
{\large QUEEN STREET.\par}}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \vfill
  \covertext
  \vfill
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: family receipt book]

## EDIT

Here's a version using the text provided in the updated question. `microtype` is used to letterspace the main title.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola,microtype,yfonts}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

{\centering

  {\small\MakeUppercase{The}\bigskip\par}
  \vfill

  {\HUGE\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{Life and Miracles}\bigskip\par}
  \vfill

  {\small\MakeUppercase{of the}\bigskip\par}
  \vfill

  {\Huge\MakeUppercase{Holy Father Benedict.}\bigskip\par}
  \vfill

  {\small\MakeUppercase{Translated from the}\bigskip\par}

  {\normalsize\MakeUppercase{Second Book of the Dialogues of St. Gregory the Great,}\bigskip\par}

  {\small\MakeUppercase{by the}\bigskip\par}

  {\Large\MakeUppercase{Rev.\ Henry Formby.}\bigskip\par}

  {\small\MakeUppercase{Followed by the}\bigskip\par}

  {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{Spirit of the Rule of St.\ Benedict,}\bigskip\par}

  {\small\MakeUppercase{By the}\bigskip\par}

  {\Large\MakeUppercase{Right Rev.\ Dr.\ Ullathorne,}\bigskip\par}

  {\small\MakeUppercase{Bishop of Birmingham.}\par}

  {\bigskip\par\normalsize\textfrak{With Ten Illustrations from Original Designs.}\par}

  \vfill
  \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par
  \vfill

  {\large\MakeUppercase{The Depot of the Pictorial Bible Stories,}\smallskip\par}

  {\normalsize\MakeUppercase{87 Great Russell Street, Birmingham:}\medskip\par}

  {\small\MakeUppercase{Sold by}\smallskip\par}

  {\large\MakeUppercase{Burns and Lambert, 17 Portman Street, London;}\smallskip\par}

  {\normalsize\MakeUppercase{J. Murphy, Baltimore.}\par}

}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: title page with microtype]

Comment: Perfect! Will come back later to check for more answers, but probably will accept as correct.

Comment: @sdegutis This is shown in the manual for `memoir` but I couldn't find the *code* there. I had to dig around a bit to find that and then adapt it somewhat. But it had the same 'feel' as the page you'd posted so I thought it might be helpful. I changed the font from the default because Computer Modern didn't feel right.  If you actually use a sans-serif in your title page, you should change that to something which complements the serif. I didn't bother here as it was just a demo.

Comment: Maybe on ctan? HAven't checked. Might be worth a mention, though. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages

Comment: @cfr Just out of curiosity, why didn't you use \scshape or something similar, rather than manually capitalizing the text here? Is there an downside to it, or was it merely that you just copy/pasted from somewhere else?

Comment: @sdegutis I just copy/pasted from `titlepages.sty`. It was already capitalised and, since your example used capitals rather than small-caps, I didn't see any reason to change it.

Comment: @Johannes_B The code is there in the documentation directory. It is just that other examples of output have code listings which match them in the manual but this title page did not. It is not that hard to find but it would not be obvious to somebody who was not somewhat familiar with TDS etc.

Comment: @sdegutis See edited answer. Note that I didn't capitalise everything when starting from non-capitalised text!

Comment: @sdegutis Thank you. Pleased you like it ;).